# How to solve wordpress website speed issue?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a website http://www.provaltech.com , from last few days I am working on speed solution for my website, I have done some r&d , also submitted website In Google PageSpeed Insights http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

I have found that its showing few errors as follows :

Leverage browser caching 
Eliminate Render-blocking JavaScript and CSS

You can check this link developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.provaltech.com%2F&tab=desktop . Here its showing all errors or you can submit my website in that tool & can check the issue.

So, can anyone help me in that? How can I solve these issues, I want to permanently remove these kind of errors.

Looking forward to hear from you experts.

Regards, 
Umar

Comment: I found this link while googling, and they have some ideas about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/DjZiusGNiIo

Comment: Side-note: You can run a MASSIVE Wordpress on any $5 server. 10.000 visitors per day, 30.000 views per day are not a problem. I'll never understand why people have "speed problems" with wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

For better page speed and avoid these error you should try following things.

1. Enable Compression from Cpanel
2. You are using Wordpress so use any of the cache plugin.
3. Use header expiry using httaccess or page header.
4. minimize you scripts (css,js).
5. Use compressed images (jpegtran,pngout).

This will help you to improve page speed.

Answer (score 1):

1)) Use caching plugin i.e best example is WP- Supercache

2)) Minify all your css and JS files i.e remove the extra white spaces from CSS and JS files.

3)) Compress all your images i.e use a plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/ or smush.it